# What does the timeGetTime() function really return?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm wondering what the `timeGetTime()` function really returns. I've powered on my system about 15 mins ago, and `timeGetTime()` returns `257052531` milliseconds which is about **71 hours**!

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timegettime) says:

> The timeGetTime function retrieves the system time, in milliseconds. The system time is the time elapsed since Windows was started.

So, my system is operating ONLY ~**15 mins**! How could it return ~**71 hours**!?

Comment: `I've powered my system about 15 min ago` are you sure the system was not in sleep mode.

Comment: Check the Up time in Task Manager Performance tab - Windows does not shutdown when you "shut it down" - My PC (not laptop) says 14+days and I shut down every night.

Comment: @t.niese Yes, absolutely bro. The system have been completely powered off before!

Comment: reboot will shut it down and restart clean. shutdown by default will a hybrid shutdown: [https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/difference-between-hybrid-shutdown-and-normal/af888b6c-ac6d-4408-a659-9259bd1e9abe](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/difference-between-hybrid-shutdown-and-normal/af888b6c-ac6d-4408-a659-9259bd1e9abe) also [https://superuser.com/questions/564119/windows-8-reports-wrong-uptime-possibly-total-hybrid-boot-uptime](https://superuser.com/questions/564119/windows-8-reports-wrong-uptime-possibly-total-hybrid-boot-uptime)